# Is Acer's GraviSense software necessary?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a three year old Acer Travelmate 6464. It's harddrive has some sort of a built in accelerometer (shock sensor, free-fall sensor, ...). The computers comes with a software called Acer GraviSense which is a little tray icon with no configurable options that tells me when the hard drive's heads have been parked due to shock.

Although it only takes less than 5MB of RAM running I'd rather not install the GraviSense software because it doesn't give me the option of changing the install path from C:/Acer/GraviSense.

So my question is: do you think that the software is nessacery for the hard drive's shock-protection feature, or do you think that the hardware itself handles the parking-of-the-drive's-heads and GraviSense is just a notification tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is scant, but both [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_hard_drive_protection) as well as [Acer's site](http://acer-uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/587/~/acer-gravisense) mentions that the software is required to issue commands to the hard drive.

> Usually the system consists of
>   accelerometers that alert the system
>   when excess acceleration or vibration
>   is detected. The software then tells
>   the hard disk to unload its heads to
>   prevent them coming in contact with
>   the platter, thus potentially
>   preventing head crash

---

> Acer GraviSense is an innovative
>   utility designed to further protect
>   your data by automatically moving the
>   read/write heads of your Acer
>   notebook's hard disk away from the
>   storage disk (this is known as
>   "parking" the heads) in the event that
>   sudden motion is detected. Acer
>   GraviSense can also be set to activate
>   an alarm in case your notebook is
>   moved by an unauthorized person.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you are right. I'll accept the answear in a day or two, unless somebody has any detailed info :)